# The Many To Many relation will not be mapped when using ADO.net entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net

I have these three tables inside my sql server but when mapping these tables using EF I will lose the table representing the M-M relation -the accountsitemapping table- and in this case I will not be able to know which accounts are linked to which sites.
To workaround this problem I just added a new column to the AccountSiteMapping table and I re-mapped the tables again then I can access the AccountSiteMapping table.

[image]

But is there a way to be able to solve this problem without the need to modify my table design ?

Comment: The accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070554/explicit-many-to-many-join-table-in-entity-framework-4 should have you good to go.

Answer (score 0):

By default entity framework will hide all mapping tables in many-to-many relationships. You will have to do your queries this way:

For example, finding `SiteDefinitions` associated with a given `org_ID`:

```
db.SiteDefinitions.Where(a => a.AccountDefinitions.Any(b => b.ORG_ID == org_ID));
```

Comment: You can read [here](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/) for more info.